# Issue with Spring Webflux webclient , nothing happens when trying to send post request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Have the following implementation of webclient :

```
    public <T> WebClient.ResponseSpec sendRequest(HttpMethod method, String contentType, T body, String baseUrl, String path) {
    try {
        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(baseUrl).filter(logRequest()).build();
        WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = webClient.method(method)
                .uri(path)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(body))
                .retrieve();
        return responseSpec;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new WebClientProcessingException("Exception when trying to execute request", e);

    }
}

// This method returns filter function which will log request data
private static ExchangeFilterFunction logRequest() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest -> {
        LOGGER.info("Request: {} {} {}", clientRequest.method(), clientRequest.url(), clientRequest.body());
        clientRequest.headers().forEach((name, values) -> values.forEach(value -> LOGGER.info("{}={}", name, value)));
        return Mono.just(clientRequest);
    });
}
```

Also have the following code , which is creating user object and command which contains user object , then calling webclient to send an request

```
@Autowired
private BaseWebClient baseWebClient;
@Override
public void saveOrUpdateUser() {
        UserPayload userPayload = new UserPayload();
        userPayload.setUserId(111L);
        userPayload.setCreatedAt(ZonedDateTime.now(DateTimeProps.systemTimeZone));
        UserCommand userCommand = new UserCommand();
        userCommand.setUser(userPayload);
        baseWebClient.sendRequest(HttpMethod.POST, "application/json",
            Stream.of(userCommand).collect(Collectors.toList()),
            "http://localhost:8080",
            "/users").onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> {
        throw new WebClientUserSaveOrUpdateeFailedException("Exception when trying to update user state")
        .bodyToMono(String.class);
    });
}
```

User payload :

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserPayload {
  Long userId;
  ZonedDateTime createdAt;
}
```

User command :

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserCommand {
     @JsonProperty("user")
     UserPayload user;
}
```

Json which is waiting for my other app (whom I am sending a request) :

```
[
  { "user":
            { 
              "userId": 1,
              "createdAt": "2019-05-16T08:24:46.412Z"
            } 
  }
]
```

Using : Spring boot 2 , Lombok (for getter/setter) , gradle 
When I'm trying to send a request nothing happens. No exception even. 
I tried with very simple case as well the same issue.
One more note, is it possible to log body? I mean somehow see final json
I guess I am missing something general.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Reactor, [nothing happens until you subscribe](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactive.subscribe). `retrive()` does not actually start the request. As you can see in the [example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.html#retrieve--), you should use one of the method to convert the ResponseSpec to a Publisher and then eventually subscribe to that publisher.

Depending on how you're using this method, you might be able to let Spring subscribe to the publisher instead. WebFlux supports reactive types in the model which means you can [directly return a Mono](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux) from your RestController methods, for example.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I am using .bodyToMono(String.class); ,  sorry question updated as well . So as far as I understand nothing else needed , right ? Or  I am missing something ?

Comment: Even by doing that, nothing ever subscribes to the Mono. You need to either call subscribe() or block() yourself, or hand the Mono off to Spring to handle.

Comment: I ended up here because of the same problem anb I managed to get out by: 1) calling block(), just to check because I did not want my client to block the thread, and it worked; 2) then I explicitly subscribed to the Mono<Void> returned by my post(), and again, it worked. I suspect that this explicit call to subscribe is normally hidden by Spring, or in @Panda's words "hand the Mono off to Spring to handle", but I haven't found any way to get rid of the call to subscribe. Does anybody know how Publisher and Subscribed can be finally bond together after calling exchangeToMono/bodyToMono?

Comment: ... so that the request can finally be released. Furthermore, calling subscribe() in the application's code I guess makes the app responsible for releasing the subscription by calling dispose(), or memory will leak.