# How to get call back when all files are uploaded?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I need to read all files from a remote location and send those to another service and the delete all files if those are sent successfully. My code is working fine for a single file but it if I want to read all files in a loop then code is not getting executed.

Please find the code as below. In RemoteFileReadImpl class, I am trying to read files in loop which is not working. In WebClientUtil class, I am sending the files to another service. On return of success response I want to rename the files which are already read.

```
package com.remotefileread.serviceImpl;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class WebClientUtil{

    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:9091");

    public Mono<HttpStatus> ftpFileSend(MultipartFile fileData) {

        MultiValueMap<String,Object> body=new LinkedMultiValueMap<String,Object>();

        try {
            body.add("file", fileData.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return webClient
                .post()
                .uri("/storeFileData")
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(body))
                .exchange()
                .map(response -> {
                    
                    return response.statusCode();
                });
    }
    
}
```

```
    package com.remotefileread.serviceImpl;
    
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.util.Base64;
    
    import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
    import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
    import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse;
    
    import com.remotefileread.model.SendFileData;
    import com.remotefileread.service.RemoteFileRead;
    
    import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
    
    @Service
    public class RemoteFileReadImpl implements RemoteFileRead{
    
        @Autowired
        WebClientUtil webClientUtil;
    
        public Mono<ServerResponse> ftpFileRead() { 
            File directoryPath = new File("\\\\localhost\\SharedFolder\\csv_container");
            File files[] = directoryPath.listFiles();
            try {
                for(File csvFile : files) {
                    SendFileData fileData=new SendFileData();   
                    byte[] content = Files.readAllBytes(csvFile.toPath());
    
                    fileData.setFilename(csvFile.getName());
                    fileData.setFileContent(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(content));
                    fileData.setCustomerName("Cust");
                    FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(csvFile);
                    MultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file",
                            csvFile.getName(),"text/plain",IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
                    input.close();
    
                    Mono<HttpStatus> monoStatus = webClientUtil.ftpFileSend(multipartFile);
    
                    monoStatus
                    .doOnSuccess( httpStatus ->
                    {
                        System.out.println("Http Status:" + httpStatus);
                        
                    })
                    .doOnError(error -> 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Http Status:" + error);
                        
                    });
                }
                return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).bodyValue("OK");
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {
                return ServerResponse.badRequest().contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).bodyValue("Error Message: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with Spring Webflux webclient , nothing happens when trying to send post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56314853/issue-with-spring-webflux-webclient-nothing-happens-when-trying-to-send-post-r)

Comment: please look up a basic tutorial about webflux or go through the https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#getting-started coding in webflux is a lot different than regular java and you are trying to code regular java in webflux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some tips on how to make your question better:

- You mentioned what you want to happen when each file succeeds, but not if one fails. Should it continue onto the next file, or stop and return a server error?
- Explain how it currently behaves, and how it differs to your expectation/desire.
- Highlight the point in your code where it's not working.

If you are using reactive, then you usually would not loop like you are doing. You would want to create a stream of the files for processing, as a `Flux`:

```
Flux.fromArray(directoryPath.listFiles())
```

Next you add operations onto the end of that stream, slowly building a "plan" of how the stream must be processed to produce a certain result.  The `Flux` above is prepared to produce the files one by one down the stream to subscribers. Note that in your code, nothing ever subscribes to the `Mono`, so nothing will ever start.

`WebClient` also returns a new stream. the `flatMap` function allows mapping elements in the stream to other streams which are then flattened in the elements' places within the original stream. In your case the web request is just returning a `Mono`.

So bearing that in mind, refactoring your code that creates the `MultipartFile` into another method `createMultipart`, and using flat map to make the web request via your util class, we would have this stream:

```
Flux<HttpStatus> statusStream = 
      Flux.fromArray(directoryPath.listFiles())
          .map(this::createMultipart)
          .flatMap(webClientUtil::ftpFileSend)
```

Let's talk about the `WebClient` usage now.

**Note that using `exchange()` (now deprecated) means that you need to be sure to consume response data, or you can cause a memory leak. Thus `exchangeToMono()` or `retrieve()` are usually better**

If you use `retrieve()`, a non-successful response will automatically raise an exception which will cause an 'error' signal in the stream, which will stop any further files from being processed.

So overall you could have an implementation like this:

```
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> ftpFileSend(MultipartFile fileData) {

        MultiValueMap<String,Object> body=new LinkedMultiValueMap<String,Object>();

        try {
            body.add("file", fileData.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return Mono.error(e);   // <-- note how to create an error signal
        }


        return webClient
                .post()
                .uri("/storeFileData")
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(body))
                .retrieve()
                .toBodilessEntity()
    }

...

    public Mono<ServerResponse> ftpFileRead() { 
    
        return Flux.fromArray(directoryPath.listFiles())
                   .flatMap(this::sendAndRename)
                   .onErrorContinue((ex, file) -> log("failed to process: " + file)) // <-- skips the erroring item and continues
                   .then(Mono.just(
                       ServerResponse.ok()
                             .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                             .bodyValue("OK"))
                   .onErrorResume(ex -> Mono.just(
                       ServerResponse.badRequest()
                             .contentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                             .bodyValue("Error Message:" + ex.getMessage())); // <-- not really a need if we just skip.
    }

    public Mono<Void> sendAndRename(final File file) {
        MultipartFile multipart = createMultipart(file);
        return webClientUtil.ftpFileSend(multipart)
                            .then(() -> renameDoneFile(file));
    }
```

Here all files are sent. If an error happens while sending or renaming, it is logged, the file skipped and the process continues with the next file.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to send the files one by one and rename the file if read successfully and print error logs if not read successfully and send the next file again.

Comment: Okay I've updated the code. That should give you an idea of how to use Reactive operators. Obviously you need to implement renameDoneFile yourself.